# I can't open a file for writing in python it gives me an error

Tags: python

```
f2=open("test3","r")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    f2=open("test3","r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test3'`
```

Comment: you arent trying to open a file for writing `r` is for reading it

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear: Python can't find the file. If you want to write to it use `'w'` instead of `'r'`. And otherwise make sure the file exists.

Comment: how can i change the default location(path) of the files? + what is the extension of the file so i can open it with python idle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is a good practice to use the context manager to open files. This helps to avoid errors caused by forgetting to close the file or things like that. This can be used in various scenarios, such as opening a database connection, opening files, etc.

```py
with open('foo.txt' , 'w') as text_file:
    # Do something
    lines = text_file.read()
    
    for line in lines:
        print(line)

print("Out of context manager")
```

The error you encountered is that python cannot find your file. Make sure the file exists. To avoid this type of error, you can specify the entire file path

```py
file_path = '/home/bar/Desktop/foo.txt'

with open(file_path , 'w') as text_file:
    # Do something
    lines = text_file.read()
    
    for line in lines:
        print(line)

print("Out of context manager")
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: how can i change the default location(path) of the files? + what is the extension of the file so i can open it with python idle?